# how to prevent a neo4j graph to have relationship with itself?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

1.How should I prevent nodes to have relationships with themselves in neo4j graph?

2.How should I force nodes to have only one relationship with each other,I mean if node A have relationship with node B this way:  A--->B, there should not be any B--->A?

I know in graph making everything is on my own so I can handle both of them,but consider there is a java api which user says which nodes and relationships should be created,but I want to prevent user from 1 and 2?

Is there any possibility in neo4j for handling them?

Comment: It sounds like you want a directed acyclic graph (DAG) - but what about cycles of longer length? Is it OK to have A-->B-->C-->A?

Comment: Sounds like a multiple personality disorder problem.

Comment: yes,it is ok to have A-->B and C--->A.

Comment: yes,exactly I want DAG,how should I have just DAG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a `[TransactionEventHandler][1]` that performs the enforcing your constraints and [register it](http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.4/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#registerTransactionEventHandler%28org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionEventHandler%29) with your GraphDatabaseService instance. A `TransactionEventHandler` can inspect the contents of the current transaction and eventually veto on committing, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-events.html.